# Cambiar variable $ jQuery a otro

Tags: javascript, jquery, librería, conflictos

Trabajo con una herramienta prefabricada para crear entrevistas, es decir, mediante una interfaz voy creando paginas y ella lo programa todo por detrás. Nosotros podemos programar cosas adicionales o modificar algunas existentes pero no podemos acceder ni modificar su código interno. Esta herramienta utiliza una versión antigua de jQuery y no podemos hacer nada con ello.

Ahora necesito incorporar una librería que crea unos efectos de zoom y lupa personalizados que me exige a su vez utilizar una versión mas moderna de jQuery. Se que no es lo mas correcto pero me gustaría incorporar esta librería moderna en conjunción con la antigua que incorpora la herramienta pero sin que entren en conflicto. El problema es que no tengo acceso a la linea en la que se enlaza jQuery de la herramienta, ya que se debe encontrar en un script interno suyo. Y si incorporo la nueva versión de jQ, como también usa $ por defecto, entrarán en conflicto automáticamente y entonces entiendo que no me servirá hacer un var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer esto atacando unicamente a una versión o en el momento que se cargan ambas no hay solución? De todos modos, imaginemos que he logrado que la antigua versión de jQ se quede usando $ (ya que la herrmienta necesita que sea así para funcionar correctamente, ya lo he probado) y la nueva usando $jq, ¿debo entonces irme al código de la libreria que crea efecto lupa sobre imagenes y reemplazar todas las llamadas a $ por $jq?

Mil gracias!

Comment: Y si lo haces con CSS? He visto buenas implementaciones de lupas o zoom sin necesidad de jQuery. Has buscado alternativas?

Comment: ¿Qué librería usas para hacer la lupa?

Comment: podrías llamar a `noConflict()` en cuanto cargas la segunda versión, para restablecer `$` a la versión anterior. Si tendrías que reemplazar todas las llamadas en la _librería_ que uses por el nuevo nombre que le des a la variable de jQ. Si tu llamada fue `jq=..` entonces sustituyes por `jq` no por `$jq` (no hay `$`)